# Pasar datos de un datagridview a un combobox (C#)

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void Modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    USUARIOS llamar = new USUARIOS();
    llamar.cbotipodepartamento.SelectedValue= 
    lista.CurrentRow.Cells["nombreD"].Value.ToString();
}
```

estoy tratando de capturar un dato de un datagridview y mostrarlo en un combobox y no me muestra

he visto que la mayoria lo hace asi pero a mi no me sale

Comment: combobox.text ??

Comment: llamar.cbotipodepartamento.SelectedValue este es el nombre de mi combo , pero tambien probe con el .text pero no me muestra

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Comunidad  Hola gracias ya solucione el problema, tenía que recargar el datasource del combo box para luego modificar el dato seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

El problema podría deberse a que la vista no puede saber de forma automática que se realizo el cambio en una propiedad

Tendrías que hacer un RaisePropertyChanged para la vista pueda darse cuenta que hubo un cambio en una propiedad y así mostrar el nuevo valor que le estas asignado

Comment: Hola, gracias ya solucione el problema, tenía que recargar el datasource del combo box para luego modificar el dato seleccionado